# Button not changing color if i use "onclick" in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

This is the demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/76Whv/

The problem is that if i do

```
<a href="#page2" data-role="button">Button2</a>
```

Then the button changes the color and everything is fine

But suppose if i try to do it using onclick like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="changetoPage2()" data-role="button">Button1</a>
```

Then the button doesn't change the color. How to solve this?

Comment: I have added your code to Fiddler -> http://jsfiddle.net/76Whv/1/ can you explain what is wrong with button "Autton"

Comment: @SATO Functionality is fine but See when you move from page2 to page1  using button2 then the button change color to blue.. I need that

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
function changetoPage2(){
  $.mobile.changePage($("#page2"), {transition : "none"});
}
```

Instead of this :

```
function changetoPage2(){
  $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {transition : "none"});
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/76Whv/3/

Comment: Still the button is not changing color.

Comment: Change page function is working fine. where are you trying to change the color of button?

Comment: Ya i know the changePage is working fine… See when you move from page2 to page1 then the button change color to blue.. I need that

Comment: That color change is due to ui-btn-active class added in active state of the button

Comment: Yes.. Js is fine. Add ui-btn-active-class through js to get the color change

Answer (score 0):

I have isulated your issue and "button"  will always tranform to blue when you click on it.
your function `function changetoPage2(){` is the cause that the button doesn't show blue.

**see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/76Whv/7/**

```
<body>
<script>
    function changetoPage2(){
   $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {transition : "none"});
}
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>Page1</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#page2" data-role="button">Button1</a>
        <a href="#page2" onclick="changetoPage2()" data-role="button">Autton1</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>Page2</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
       <a href="#page1" data-role="button">Button2</a>
       <a href="#page1" onclick="changetoPage1()" data-role="button">Autton2</a>
    </div>

</div>
</body>​
```

Comment: I know that if i put `href=#page2` then it will change color. In real scenario i dont want to change a page. I want to invoke a function. Thats why i have shown in my fiddle.